# Unexpected delay while returning a string

Tags: c++, function, return, delay

Would there be a reason that there would be a delay upon return a string from a function?

Background Info:
I made a simple program that takes an input of letters and outputs any anagrams of those letters. It checks the words from a very large text file of thousands of words. It basically puts each word into a vector and checks if its an anagram of the letters, and prints it out if it is. It usually does this in 1-15 seconds, which I am satisfied with.

The problem occurred when I tried converting it into a function that instead returns the string that is an anagram. Even though it still "cout"s the word at the same speed, it takes about 20 seconds after this to actually return the string and cout.

Why would it take so much longer to actually return a string than just outputting it, and how can I fix it?

I can post my code if necessary;

Edit:
I uploaded the project as a zip, since it has 15 files.

http://www.mediafire.com/?c2gizpgcweg3iy4

Brace yourself for the shock of viewing the car crash that is my code.

Comment: Please post the code. It's hard to troubleshoot something without the code...

Comment: maybe a lot of stuff goes out of scope and destruction takes some time?

Comment: Are you compiling with optimizations on? This can make a dramatic difference with standard library algorithms, containers, and strings.

Comment: Is there no way to simplify the code and reduce it to a minimal example that can be used to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I'm not really sure how, because I don't have the same problem when I only use a short list of words to check.

Comment: @Nick That actually makes sense, since my vectors are huge with all the possible words, guess I didn't expect destruction to take so long. Is there a way to destruct after returning the string, or at least keep it from taking as long?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger to see what it does? Or checked the generated assembly code to see what really happens?

Answer (score 0):

If I were going to do this, I think I'd use either an `multimap<string, string>` or a `map<string, std::vector<string> >` (the two are roughly equivalent).

I'd start by reading in the list of words. As I read each word, I'd create a copy and sort the letters in that copy. Then I'd insert the sorted/original pair into the [multi]map, with the sorted version as the key.

When I needed to look for the anagrams of a word, I'd sort that word, look in the map for the sorted version, and get all the original words that match that sorted version. After that, you can do pretty much whatever you want with them.

As far as size and speed go, I'd expect one file of, say, 39 lines, and the ability to read input and print out matching anagrams at a rate of about 3000 words per second (if you prefer to look at it differently figure around 15 kilobytes of input per second). Of course, that estimate (?) is based on my 6 year-old machine. With a newer computer, you should be able to do quite a bit better.

Since all the words are loaded during input, I would not expect this to slow down to any perceptible degree if you return words rather than printing them out (in fact, I'd expect it to speed up somewhat if you don't print out results at all).